# Android - RecyclerView display wrong items after adding new ones

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, viewmodel

I am working on a WebSocket-based chat application and I am having troubles to add new incoming messages to the RV (RecyclerView).

I have the following adapter's overriten functions

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): UserChatMessagesAdapter.Holder {
        val binding = AdapterUserChatMessagesRvBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return Holder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindData(messages[position])
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = messages.size
```

The data comes from API calls and are posted by a ViewModel through `LiveData`.

For testing purposes, on the first connection, I am returning only 10 messages to be displayed. Then, when scrolling, I return the following 10 and so on.

> I am not having issues to populate already existing message from the
> past when scrolling.

**Problem adding new messages**

The problem is when User A sends messages to User B (or viceversa), the messages are not being displayed correctly.

For example, supposing I have already displayed the messages: M1, M2, ..., M10.

Then User A sends **M11**. But instead of displaying that new M11, it is displaying another one, such as, M3 (or any other, I haven't detected a pattern).

The adapter's method to display a new message:

```kotlin
fun newMessage(newMessage: ChatMessageView) {
   val index = LAST_MESSAGE_INDEX
   messages.add(index, newMessage)
   notifyItemInserted(index)
}
```

> When debugging I didn't find anything wrong. The `newMessage` value is
> the expected one and the `messages` list is updated correctly. I
> doesn't seem a data issue.
>
> The messages **are cached in memory**, so when re-entering to the
> chat, they are not requested again to the API.  Having said that, when
> I re-enter to the chat, the messages are displayed correctly.

I have also tried:

- Using `notifyDataSetChanged`.
- Replacing the entire `messages` list
- Smooth scroller (I've read somewhere it may be a problem related to the fast user scrolling)
- Overriding the methods `getItemViewType`, `getItemId`.
- Setting `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)`

If it helps, this is the Holder definition:

```kotlin
inner class Holder(private val binding: AdapterUserChatMessagesRvBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bindData(message: ChatMessageView) {
        if (message.isSentByMe) {
            binding.userChatMessagesAdapterSentMessage.configure(
                SentMessageComponent.Configuration(
                    message.content,
                    message.sentMoment.time
                )
            )
            binding.userChatMessagesAdapterSentMessage.visible()
        } else {
            binding.userChatMessagesAdapterReceivedMessage.configure(
                ReceivedMessageComponent.Configuration(
                    message.content,
                    message.sentMoment.time
                )
            )
            binding.userChatMessagesAdapterReceivedMessage.visible()
        }

            configureDateSeparator(message.sentMoment.date)
    }
```

And this my custom `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` definition:

```kotlin
internal abstract class PaginationScrollListener(
    private val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    abstract fun isLastPage(): Boolean

    abstract fun isLoading(): Boolean

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
            val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
            val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
            val firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

            if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
                loadMoreItems()
            }
        }
    }

    abstract fun loadMoreItems()
}
```

**--------- EDIT - 1 ---------**

I add the corresponding XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adapter_chat_room_main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp">

    <...components.ChatDateSeparatorComponent
        android:id="@+id/user_chat_messages_adapter_date_separator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <...components.ReceivedMessageComponent
        android:id="@+id/user_chat_messages_adapter_received_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_chat_messages_adapter_date_separator" />

    <...components.SentMessageComponent
        android:id="@+id/user_chat_messages_adapter_sent_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_chat_messages_adapter_date_separator" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bindData` function makes a component visible depending on the message type, but it doesn't make the other component *invisible* - so if that `ViewHolder` is used to display an item where `isSentByMe` is *true*, and then you scroll down and it gets reused for an item where `isSentByMe` is *false*, `userChatMessagesAdapterSentMessage` and `userChatMessagesAdapterReceivedMessage` will both be visible.

I'm guessing those are two different `View`s in your layout - you haven't shown your XML, but is it possible the `ViewHolder`'s height is fixed (not `wrap_content`) so the lower of those two views is outside the visible area? Or maybe one overlays the other, so you can only see the top one?

---

**edit:** yeah see, you're overlaying them on each other:

```
<...components.ChatDateSeparatorComponent
    android:id="@+id/user_chat_messages_adapter_date_separator"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<...components.ReceivedMessageComponent
    android:id="@+id/user_chat_messages_adapter_received_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_chat_messages_adapter_date_separator" />

<...components.SentMessageComponent
    android:id="@+id/user_chat_messages_adapter_sent_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_chat_messages_adapter_date_separator" />
```

*Both* have their tops constrained to the bottom of the `separator` view that's pinned to the top - so vertically they're in the exact same place. One's constrained to the left and the other to the right, but their widths are both `match_parent` so they fill the whole width anyway.

If both of those `MessageComponent` views are `visible`, only the `SentMessage` one will be seen since it's specified last (drawn on top of the other because it has a higher Z-order). If the `ReceivedMessage` one has significantly more content making it taller (because both their heights are `wrap_content`) then it'll peek out below the other.

Like I said, **you're only setting them to visible** in the code you posted. You never set the other one to *invisible/gone* to make sure it's hidden. You're not toggling between showing one or the other, you show one and then it sticks as visible even if that `ViewHolder` needs to show the other type of message. So according to your XML, if a *sent* message is displayed in that `ViewHolder`, you won't be able to see any *received* messages that it ends up displaying as you scroll, and you'll just see the old *sent* content.

That's why you're probably seeing **M3** instead of **M11** - because a VH that was previously displaying **M3** is being reused, **M11** is displayed, but you can't see it behind the old **M3** content. And if you "re-enter the chat" and everything's basically reset, it's possible that you'll see **M11** in a VH that hasn't been used to display a *sent* message yet, so it looks ok (but stuff will probably break if you scroll up and back down again).

---

In case you don't know, the point of a `RecyclerView` is to *reuse* (recycle) a handful of `ViewHolder`s, using them to display the data for a specific item. In `onBindViewHolder` you're given one of those ViewHolders, which **may have already been used to display something else**, and you set it up to display your current item.

That bit in bold is important, because it means the VH will have old state, including in your case a `View` that's been set to visible. So you have to explicitly set the state for *everything* so there's no old state left over - assume it's dirty and needs setting up completely. That means when you set one of your `View`s to `VISIBLE`, you **have to** set the other to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`. Otherwise if it was visible before, now you have two visible things, and that's a problem!

So you have to do this:

```
if (message.isSentByMe) {
    binding.userChatMessagesAdapterSentMessage.configure(
        SentMessageComponent.Configuration(
            message.content,
            message.sentMoment.time
        )
    )
    binding.userChatMessagesAdapterSentMessage.visible()
    // explicitly hide the other one - I'm assuming you'll write another function
    binding.userChatMessagesAdapterReceivedMessage.invisible()
} else {
    binding.userChatMessagesAdapterReceivedMessage.configure(
        ReceivedMessageComponent.Configuration(
            message.content,
            message.sentMoment.time
        )
    )
    binding.userChatMessagesAdapterReceivedMessage.visible()
    // same as the other branch - you're showing this, make sure the other is hidden
    binding.userChatMessagesAdapterSentMessage.invisible()
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I didn't mention it but, by default, both are invisible and are made visible depending on the isSentByMe.
I will add the XML to be clearer but it's all handled in a unique XML (could be better). So it doesn't sound to me it's related to overlapping views.

Comment: @GreatNews yeah it's like I said, your views in the XML overlap and you're only making them visible without hiding the other again. I've edited my answer with some more detail, that should fix it hopefully!

Comment: oh man, it worked!! thank you very much.. I've been struggling with this for hours :(
however, I don't understand something. Despite I wasn't hiding the other programatically, as you can see in the XML, by default, the components are set as gone. Why it is not enough?

Comment: @GreatNews it's because the `ViewHolder` is reused - the XML just describes how it should be set up when it's first created, same as a `TextView` having no text in it, a `CheckBox` being unticked, etc. But once it's created, you can change those things. When you scroll down to **M11** or whatever, it's not creating a fresh `ViewHolder` with those defaults and things set to *gone* - you're (generally) getting one that's already been used, looking exactly how it was set up when you displayed **M3** or whatever, because it's the same object being displayed again! So you need to configure it

Comment: aah okey, now I get it. Again, thank you very much!!

Comment: @GreatNews That's the point of a `RecyclerView` - it recycles a pool of `ViewHolder` objects, instead of inflating a layout into a completely new set of `View`s for every single list item (which is how the old `ListView` worked) - so when you display an item, you get handed one of those reusable ViewHolders. It's way more efficient, but it means you have to set up the VH completely each time so you're not left with any old state. Wipe it clean, y'know? No worries, hope it makes sense! That "set the state for *everything* that might have changed" part always trips people up